# Upgrade from Helios to Indigo with Helios version having many working sets

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, helios

I am sure somebody might have come across this scenario.

I have many working sets in my present workspace (Eclipse Helios version). I am trying to migrate the same to Indigo SR2 version.

Simple workspace migration from one version of Eclipse to another also I have not done earlier.

Please let me know how to proceed with the same

Answer (score 1):

Normally, everything should go fine when you install all the plug-ins in Indigo which you have in Helios. Then you just open your workspace with Helios, you are good to go, but of course, a full workspace compilation might be done.

As far as I know, Indigo used to have some problems with Maven support, I don't know if it has been fixed.